# Is free MS Developer login enough to register my App in Azure

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am a Delphi Developer using Microsoft Graph API to store my application's data on Onedrive. My application will be given to several customers and will run for years (hopefully). For this I need to register my Application on Azure. Currently I have used the free Microsoft Developer account to register my application. Is this sufficient or do I have to purchase something from Microsoft ?
edit:
I am using it to backup data of the users overcoming the typical drawbacks that Onedrive has. It is not hosted on the web, it is run from the user's machine as a Windows Service Application. I need to register it to get for the ClientID and refreshToken etc. and One time sign-In

Comment: There's really no way to know what you'll need, regarding Azure, without doing some examination of the services (and tiers) offered to you, along with some benchmarking on your side. Plus, you've shared no code or specific issues, so at this point, you'd only get guesses and speculation (it's unclear what you're using Azure for).

Comment: What is you application? If it is not hosted in Azure but just access data on OneDrive via the OneDrive API I don't see why it needs anything to be registered? You would need to keep whatever OneDrive account you are using in good standing of course.

Comment: I have edited my initial question as per experts suggestions,  please tell me what account do I need to Register to get a Authorised Client ID